# How this string is showing up in http link?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, http

http://10.12.12.169:8000/(S(s2u3p445aiiswvrogmva4o3i))/Pilot/Login.aspx

I do not know why and how this thing "(S(s2u3p445aiiswvrogmva4o3i))" shows up in my http link.
Is it something with my website setup. I am using sharepoint to host my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aristos said, it appears to be a cookieless url. To further elaborate on this please see the MSDN documentation on the matter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx.